# Как обрезать лишние переносы строк в тексте из textarea перед сохранением в бд

Tags: php, html, textarea

Как обрезать лишние переносы строк в тексте из textarea перед сохранением в бд

[image: Как обрезать лишние переносы строк в тексте из textarea перед сохранением в бд]

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений PHP, используя `preg_replace()`.

Можно с помощью SQL. Для MySQL например, вот так:

```
insert into my_users (first_name, last_name, birthday, email)
values (regexp_replace('J o  h   n', ' +', ''), 'Doe', '1969-12-31', 'john.doe@example.com');
```

[image: Результат запроса]

---

### `preg_replace()`

```php
$text = '

Lorem
ipsum

dolor


sit



amet

';

echo preg_replace('=\n+=', "\n", trim($text));
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/PertinentSourTransversal#main.php

Comment: интересноо тогда как бы через preg_replace() ))

Comment: @АлександрЛиссов, https://replit.com/@w3lifer/PertinentSourTransversal